# Localized country names

Tags: localization, internationalization

Where can I get the country names in all languages? I need these to localize an application.

Comment: Do you only want the official name of each country which would be around 246 country names or do you want this for N languages giving 246*N country names? In the second case I think you need to limit the number of languages.

Comment: i got the official names of all countries. I am looking for country names in languages: french (France,Canada), spanish (chile, spain), Portuguese, Hindi, Chinese, Japanese, German

Comment: Wikipedia is *not* the best place to get this information, specially because is kind incomplete. Check my answer for an official source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The proper location to get this information from is [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org).

There you can find an [updated list of countries](http://www.unicode.org/Public/cldr/latest) (`core/common/main`), the data is available in numerous formats.

Comment: And it's vetted and in XML format, ready to consume. No 'scraping' needed.

Comment: https://github.com/karmi/localized_country_select - this is a working example with Ruby on Rails

Comment: Is it me or is it really hard to find the XML doc with the data? I'd be grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: Hi! I am finding it hard to find the XML data fro the resource mentioned above, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 12):

I recommend this site: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list

> List of all countries with names and ISO 3166-1 codes in all languages
>   and data formats.

Comment: This is really great. Available in every language and in the most common formats like SQL, XML, JSON, CSV, PHP. Love it!

Comment: Just so you know, i tried to match the list of countries in a specific language with the English one from 3166 and not all countries matched, i think 2 or 3 missed the mark, so be careful, see if all data matches before trusting the translation. The ones that wont match you can get from the net it will hardly be wrong. I just wanted to point it out here. I used the data to populate my own table with the countries, i would not recommend to use the data as is, since it needs some adjustment

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an ISO standard document you can buy (a useful standard is [ISO 3166-1](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm), I think).

On the other hand, you might just be able to scrape through the various language versions of [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1), since it has a list of country names. I did a random check and it seemed the entire list was in at least one non-English language, too.

Comment: The ISO 3166-1 is about country codes. However, if I understand the question correctly Pangea wants a list of all country names in all languages. E.g. Danmark (da), Denmark (en), Dänemark (de), Dinamarca (es) etc.

Answer (score 1):

A know this is an old post but I found something that might help others who end up viewing this post via a google search.

This alternative to a select list gives (some) localised country names.

[selectToAutocomplete by Jamie Appleseed](https://github.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete/blob/master/index.html)

Take a look at the data-alternate-spelling tag for the items within the select menu.

Answer (score 0):

IP2Location provide a free CSV formatted list of country names in 81 different languages. I've found this the most useful list for this purpose. The data can be fairy easily transformed into different formats if required:

https://www.ip2location.com/free/country-multilingual