# Does anyone know a library containing all localized country names in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Localized country names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724970/localized-country-names)

Is there any java lib that contains all countries localized in the main european languages?

I've tried using `java.util.Locale` but it doesn't contain all the the countries (it's missing some like san marino, andorra, azerbeijan...)

---

EDIT

This:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales())
    {
         System.out.println(locale.getCountry() + "  " + locale.getDisplayCountry());
    }
```

Outputs this: (my locale is english)

```
AE  United Arab Emirates
AL  Albania
AR  Argentina
AT  Austria
AU  Australia
BA  Bosnia and Herzegovina
BE  Belgium
BG  Bulgaria
BH  Bahrain
BO  Bolivia
BR  Brazil
BY  Belarus
CA  Canada
CH  Switzerland
CL  Chile
CN  China
CO  Colombia
CR  Costa Rica
CS  Serbia and Montenegro
CY  Cyprus
CZ  Czech Republic
DE  Germany
DK  Denmark
DO  Dominican Republic
DZ  Algeria
EC  Ecuador
EE  Estonia
EG  Egypt
ES  Spain
FI  Finland
FR  France
GB  United Kingdom
GR  Greece
GT  Guatemala
HK  Hong Kong
HN  Honduras
HR  Croatia
HU  Hungary
ID  Indonesia
IE  Ireland
IL  Israel
IN  India
IQ  Iraq
IS  Iceland
IT  Italy
JO  Jordan
JP  Japan
KR  South Korea
KW  Kuwait
LB  Lebanon
LT  Lithuania
LU  Luxembourg
LV  Latvia
LY  Libya
MA  Morocco
ME  Montenegro
MK  Macedonia
MT  Malta
MX  Mexico
MY  Malaysia
NI  Nicaragua
NL  Netherlands
NO  Norway
NZ  New Zealand
OM  Oman
PA  Panama
PE  Peru
PH  Philippines
PL  Poland
PR  Puerto Rico
PT  Portugal
PY  Paraguay
QA  Qatar
RO  Romania
RS  Serbia
RU  Russia
SA  Saudi Arabia
SD  Sudan
SE  Sweden
SG  Singapore
SI  Slovenia
SK  Slovakia
SV  El Salvador
SY  Syria
TH  Thailand
TN  Tunisia
TR  Turkey
TW  Taiwan
UA  Ukraine
US  United States
UY  Uruguay
VE  Venezuela
VN  Vietnam
YE  Yemen
ZA  South Africa
```

---

## Before you click "close" read the questions:

This question is not a dupe of the candidate duplicated question! The other question is not related with java in any way! It even has objective-c code in it!

Comment: Acconding to the docs (of `java.util.Locale`): "The country argument is a valid ISO Country Code. These codes are the upper-case, two-letter codes as defined by ISO-3166. You can find a full list of these codes at a number of sites, such as: 
http://www.iso.ch/iso/en/prods-services/iso3166ma/02iso-3166-code-lists/list-en1.html". The previous link has all the countries you mentioned. Did I missed something?

Comment: @pankar yeah but Locale doesn't output all of them. I edited the question with the output

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724970/localized-country-names][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724970/localized-country-names

Comment: @pangea that question is not related with java

Comment: I understand the need to track down and close duplicate questions. but closing this one seems a bit excessive. maybe one of the users, who voted for the close, can explain their reasons.

Comment: @martin don't worry yourself :p nobody is going to look at this question again, thanks for the reply though ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Locale.getISOCountries()`. For example the following code prints the German names of all countries defined in ISO 3166.

```
Locale locale = Locale.GERMAN;      
for (String country : Locale.getISOCountries())
{
    System.out.println(new Locale("", country).getDisplayCountry(locale));
}
```

This uses the `LocaleNames_xx.properties` resource bundles. [Here's the default version in the JDK repository.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/57148c79bd75/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/util/resources/LocaleNames.properties#l868)

**Update, 13.05.2020:** The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry()) states that this will return `a name for the locale's country that is appropriate for display to the user.` While there is some overlap, the above code will not always return the ISO-3166 name. There is a [JDK bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8245072) discussing this. See my comments below for more details.

Comment: that sounds good, just needs a api wrapper around it for easier access :)

Comment: of course. depending on your use case, it might also be a good idea to return a sorted collection.

Comment: In fact, this list does not returns the official ISO country names, for example, Russia is not the official ISO name, if you take a look on the iso.org website you could see it https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:RU

Comment: This is a good point. In fact, there are quite a few differences between the ISO and the display names. I collected them here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kpx08RNV4eQyDWnQBD80DjfefxFnVVEhC5DjsSugPZc

On closer inspection, the Javadoc only states that the name returned is appropriate for display to the user: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry().

That could explain why "Russia" has been chosen instead of "Russian Federation". The problematic part is that this has not been done consistently for every country.

Comment: That said, there are some country names that are clearly wrong:
CV should be "Cabo Verde",
CZ should be "Czechia",
MK should be "North Macedonia",
SZ should be "Eswatini".

Quite a few others could also be argued to be changed.

In short, if the requirement is strictly ISO-3166 compliant country names, it seems Java does not provide this out-of-the-box.

I have raised a bug report with Oracle to update some of the more obvious mistakes.

Comment: Java 17 country names list: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/4afbcaf55383ec2f5da53282a1547bac3d099e9d/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/util/resources/LocaleNames.properties#L868